# WPF MouseMove on Grid, update Position on Object Instance

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to bind the mousemove event to an instance of an object, and then update some properties in this object, how can I go about doing this? Below is my XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <h:AdaptiveObject x:Key="adaptiveObject" />
    </Window.Resources>
   <Grid Name="Container"
            MouseMove="{Binding Source={StaticResource adaptiveObject}, Path=UpdateMouse}"
```

And here is the current C# I have, which is just concept and doesn't work, just want to show you what i'm attempting:

```
namespace AdaptiveViewport
{
    public class AdaptiveObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public int MouseX { get; set; }
        public int MouseY { get; set; }

        public UpdateMouse(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MouseX = e.X;
            MouseY = e.Y;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MouseMove is a Event you cant simply bind it to a Command. One way to achieve what you want would be to use a method in your code-behind:

```
    <Grid MouseMove="OnMouseMove" Name="Container">...</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  var p = Mouse.GetPosition(Container);
  // p.X and p.Y are your coordinates here 
}
```

You can probably also use blend interactivity features but i couldn't figure out how to pass the coordinates to a bound command.